# RDLC - Previous Page Total in reports Body

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, rdlc

with my reports Tablix, I wish to have a Previous Page Total on Firstline of Current Page in Reports Body...Is it possible? 
While I make some Invoices, On the 2nd page I wish to put the 1st page total like the below... I required it in reports body ...
but for Header & Footer no problem... Therefore my TextBox expression looks like the below..But it 
gives error

```
"PageNumber or TotalPages can be used in Header or Footer"

=IIF(Globals!PageNumber >1,"Brought Forward - PAGE - " & Globals!PageNumber -1," ") ???????
```

And my value TexBox expression will be

```
=SUM(Fields!amount_value.Value )   ???????????
```

Thanks

Comment: Given this has been up for a month or so with no answer whatsoever, I'm going to chip in with my two penn'orth: I *suspect* that this isn't possible, because AFAIK the report isn't paginated until after it's built, and even not completely paginated till you go into Print Preview. So at the time you can do totals, there's no such thing as a page; and by the time you have a page, it's too late to do any maths.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Peter, because of my a/c lack, I cannot reply, Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Just find sum for the entire dataset then reduce the group level total from main dataset.

SUM(Price,"dsFullData") - SUM(Price,"grplevelTotal)

This should work

Thanks,
Nagarajan